# How do I change security for an existing named pipe?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, named-pipes, hyper-v

I'm using Hyper V on Windows 8 and would like to be able to communicate with the virtual serial port through a named pipe. I give the pipe a name of choice and it works well communicating with the virtual os (XP, in my case) serial port, but only under the Admin user due to PipeSecurity settings.

Now I would like to be able to give full control for everyone on a named pipe created by Hyper-V. Programmatically or maybe with some Hyper V setting. I need to be able to communicate with the virtual os as a regular User.

I know how to set a certain security on a named pipe that I create myself using NamedPipeServerStream together with a PipeSecurity object. I'm mainly using C#, but I see that there are C++ API:s like SetSecurityInfo. But these requires a handle to the existing pipe.

In pseudo code I would like to do something like:

SetSecurityInfo("mypipe", new PipeAccessRule("Everyone", PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

Anyone know how to do this? (C++ or preferrably C#)

Comment: It might be possible to open the client end of the pipe with CreateFile and then use that handle with SetSecurityInfo.  I'd try an access mode of WRITE_DAC first, but you may need to experiment a bit.  Enabling SeBackupPrivilege and SeRestorePrivilege before calling CreateFile might help too.  Try it in C first, C# would just complicate things, if you get it working in C you always can port it later.  Failing all else, write a service that opens the named pipe on behalf of a client process.  You can use DuplicateHandle to copy the handle into the client process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get a working C++ solution. Harry's idea to embed this code in a service might be necessary for named pipes that aren't permanent in the system.

```
HANDLE hPipe = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\mypipe", GENERIC_WRITE | WRITE_DAC, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);  
if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{      

  PACL pOldDACL = NULL;  
  if(GetSecurityInfo(hPipe, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, &pOldDACL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
    TRUSTEE trustee[1];
    trustee[0].TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_NAME;
    trustee[0].TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP;
    trustee[0].ptstrName = _T("Everyone");
    trustee[0].MultipleTrusteeOperation = NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE;
    trustee[0].pMultipleTrustee = NULL;

    EXPLICIT_ACCESS explicit_access_list[1];
    ZeroMemory(&explicit_access_list[0], sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));

    explicit_access_list[0].grfAccessMode = GRANT_ACCESS;
    explicit_access_list[0].grfAccessPermissions = GENERIC_ALL;
    explicit_access_list[0].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
    explicit_access_list[0].Trustee = trustee[0];

    PACL pNewDACL = NULL;
    if(SetEntriesInAcl(1, explicit_access_list, pOldDACL, &pNewDACL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
      if(SetSecurityInfo(hPipe, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, pNewDACL, NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
      {
        //Error handling              
        DWORD dw = GetLastError();          
      }
      LocalFree(pNewDACL);
    }
    else
    {
      //Error handling        
      GetLastError();
    }
    LocalFree(pOldDACL);
  }
  else
  {
    //Error
    GetLastError();
  }
}
else
{
  //Error handling
  DWORD dw = GetLastError();       
}  
CloseHandle(hPipe);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this on MSDN. Looks easy enough to follow:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365600(v=vs.85).aspx

Reading the article if you SetSecurityInfo on PSID of your user group then it should be doable.